# Unclear Polish case usage

Tags: grammar, polish

I saw the following two constructions in Polish:

- Za około dwadzieścia minut
- Po około dwudziestu minutach

And I don't really understand their grammatical rules.

*Za* takes accusative, 20 and *około* take genitive, and *po* takes locative.

However, in the first sentence the number 20 is not declined and *minut* is declined regularly, but in the second sentence, *po* declines both the number 20 *and* the word *"minut"*.

Can someone please explain the construction and what word dictates the declination?

Comment: This is quite easy to find online. The particle _około_ [has no effect on case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/około#Particle) (unlike the _preposition_, which does). [Wikipedia also explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_grammar#Numbers_and_quantifiers) that if the numeral is in the nominative or accusative, the noun will be in the genitive plural; whereas if the numeral is in the genitive, dative, instrumental or locative, the noun will normally be in the same case.

Comment: Great, add it as an answer and I'll star it, I wasn't aware that około can be both a particle and a preposition (nor I know what a particle is).